# Change name and numbering of block title

Tags: beamer, numbering, block

I'm trying to make the following changes to the default settings in Beamer:

1. Instead of the usual numbering of the blocks (1, 2, 3), I would like to add a prefix: (A.1, A.2, A.3).
2. I would also like to change the word "Example" to "Exercise" for the `\begin{example}` block.

How do I do these adjustments? For the second one, I'm planning to create a `\begin{exercise}` command instead, but I have no idea how to create one.

```
\documentclass{beamer}

\usetheme{Boadilla}
\usecolortheme{whale}
\setbeamertemplate{theorems}[numbered]

\begin{document}

\begin{frame}{Title}
    \begin{theorem}
        Theorem A.1, not Theorem 1.
    \end{theorem}
    \begin{example}
        Change `Example 2' to `Exercise A.2'.
    \end{example}
    \begin{definition}
        Definition A.3
    \end{definition}
\end{frame}

\end{document}
```

[image]

Answer (score 3):

[image: new block environment]

When the theorem environment is used, the overlay specifications have to follow the "block beginning template" upon invocation. So we have to use it to add the optional argument `\inserttheoremaddition` that may let us **change the block title**.

Put this code in the preamble to add **A.** before the numbers.

```
% ------------- Adding letter A before numbers ----------
    \setbeamertemplate{theorem begin}
    {%
    \begin{\inserttheoremblockenv}
        {\inserttheoremname~A\inserttheorempunctuation\ignorespaces\inserttheoremnumber}%
    }\setbeamertemplate{theorem end}
    {    \end{\inserttheoremblockenv}}
```

On the other hand, to create a **new block environment** called exercise, we have use `\def\th@newblock` command. Now you can create an exercise block in the document section by `\begin{exercise}`. Notice that the example environment `\begin{example}` still being available (as shown in the image above). I have modified a bit the answer posted [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2600355/how-do-i-change-the-block-template-for-specific-theorem-environments-latex-beam). So, you should also add next code in the preamble section.

```
% ------------- Creating a new block template ----------
\makeatletter
\def\th@newblock{%
  \normalfont 
  \def\inserttheoremblockenv{exampleblock}}
\theoremstyle{newblock}
\newtheorem{exercise}[theorem]{Exercise}
\makeatother
```

Additionally, you can change the "color" or style of this block, changing `exampleblock` for `alertblock` or any other option.

Finally, this is your new code:

```
\documentclass{beamer}
\usetheme{Boadilla}
\usecolortheme{whale}
\setbeamertemplate{theorems}[numbered]

% ------------- Adding letter A before numbers ----------
\setbeamertemplate{theorem begin}
{%
\begin{\inserttheoremblockenv}
    {\inserttheoremname~A\inserttheorempunctuation\ignorespaces\inserttheoremnumber}%
}
\setbeamertemplate{theorem end}
{    \end{\inserttheoremblockenv}}

% ------------- Creating a new block template ----------
\makeatletter
\def\th@newblock{%
  \normalfont 
  \def\inserttheoremblockenv{exampleblock}}
\theoremstyle{newblock}
\newtheorem{exercise}[theorem]{Exercise}
\makeatother

% ------------- Document ----------
\begin{document}

\begin{frame}{Title}
    \begin{theorem}
        Theorem A.1, not Theorem 1.
    \end{theorem}
    \begin{exercise}            % using the new exercise command !
        Change `Example 2' to `Exercise A.2'.
    \end{exercise}
    \begin{definition}
        Definition A.3
    \end{definition}
    \begin{example}
        Example block is still working 
    \end{example}
\end{frame}

\end{document}
```

This is the first answer I post, so let me know if I wasn't clear enough. Regards.

Comment: Is there a simple way to change the default block names without really defining new environments?